# ¿para que sirve la etiqueta <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"?

Tags: html5, navegador-web

Me he encontrado con la etiqueta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
```

Sé que sirve para para la compatibilidad, he encontrado esta pagina:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/cc817574.aspx pero me gustaría saber si alguien me puede dar un poco mas de información de como funciona.
Gracias

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La vista de compatibilidad es una característica que fue incorporada en Internet Explorer 8, que permiten al navegador mostrar las páginas web que no cumplen con los estándares como si corrieran en versiones anteriores de IE.

Cómo funciona la vista de compatibilidad?

La vista de compatibilidad le permite al usuario o al navegador establecer el modo de compatibilidad, por defecto el navegador identifica la vista de compatibilidad por medio de la versión del navegador establecida en el User Agent.

También se puede establecer una lista de compatibilidad, donde antes de mostrar el sitio web lee esta lista y verifica si el sitio web está en modo compatibilidad o no.

Answer (score -1):

A día de hoy, 2021, Microsoft ya no recomienda el uso de ésta meta etiqueta y en su lugar definir el documento como HTML5 con DOCTYPE.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-iedoco/380e2488-f5eb-4457-a07a-0cb1b6e4b4b5?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Sin embargo, frente a proyectos sobre versiones de IE 7/8 y frente a errores o etiquetas DEPRECIATED podría resultar interesante emplearla para evaluar resultados.

Comment: Sería bueno incluir para qué servía antes y por qué ha sido remplazada o ya no se usa, no solo referirse a que ya está en desuso. La duda de la pregunta queda, aún no sé para que sirve la etiqueta meta, solo sé que ya no se usa.

Comment: @sarevalo ya mencionó cual es su función, básicamente eso se colocaba antes para darle la posibilidad a usuarios que están usando navegadores viejos como Internet Explorer 7 u 8 para que puedan ver bien tu página web que está creada con códigos mas modernos si es tu caso.